# RedeliveryDelay with JmsTransactionManager plugged to ActiveMQ not working properly

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am facing an issue with an ActiveMQ consumer in Java using the `JmsTransactionManager`.

I set a `RedeliveryPolicy` on the `ConnectionFactory` as follows:

```java
RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
redeliveryPolicy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(10000);
redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(5);
redeliveryPolicy.setRedeliveryDelay(10000);
```

```
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(amqUri);
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setWatchTopicAdvisories(false);
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy);
```

And I configured the transaction manager like this :

```java
JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager = new JmsTransactionManager();
jmsTransactionManager.setConnectionFactory(amqPooledConnectionFactory);
DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
container.setConnectionFactory(amqPooledConnectionFactory);
container.setTransactionManager(jmsTransactionManager);
```

Then on every exception thrown I am expecting (related to the `RedeliveryPolicy`) that the message is redelivered maximum 5 times every 10 seconds.

The problem here is that the `RedeliveryDelay` does not work at all and the message is redelivered 5 times quickly without waiting for 10 seconds. (`maxRedeliveries` works well)

Has someone got that issue before?

Some information about versions:

- ActiveMQ Broker: 5.16.2
- ActiveMQ Java Driver: 5.16.2
- Spring JMS: 5.3.6

Comment: Please share the code where the redelivery policy is wired into the ConnectionFactory

Comment: @MattPavlovich I edited the code above with my ActiveMQConnectionFactory configuration. Thanks in advance. :)